# Puzzling struggle in Signup to GCP - error [OR-CBAT-09]

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform

The very beginnings on GCP turn out as a real struggle. Just on the signup page (all access $300 free) receiving error message: "This payment method can't be used for recurring payments [OR-CBAT-09]" also the bank account shows "unverified".

What's been tried: signing in on Google pay - trying to enter the verification code: doesn't show any place to enter code from the wire transfer. Also contacting various Google supports by chat (hours :) ) Cloud Billing Support apparently is responsible yet available only to registered users - real dilemma.

Thank you very much for any tips here

Comment: No details, so we can only guess. Some payment methods are not supported. What are you using and where in the world are you? Example: for some countries debit cards cards are not supported. For more information, this link might help: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods

Comment: Thank you your response. Sorry I'm afraid don't quite follow there. What further details would be important to provide? It's an EU bank account, the test amount by wire transfer was received. There's nowhere on Google pay to enter that code. Thank you

Comment: No details, so we can only guess. Contact Google Cloud Billing Support https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: I'm sorry, no details? As stated, Cloud Billing Support is only available to registered users.

Comment: Billing support is free to all customers. What is your definition of registered users? You have provided no details. What country, what payment method, what page are you getting an error, etc. You received: "This payment method can't be used". Use a different supported payment method. I provided links to help you.

Comment: As it was mentioned by @John Hanley [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) offer free of charge Basic support plan that covers "Billing support and read-only access to break/fix cases". Have you tried to contact them?

Answer (score 1):

Sign up on the Play store and create a merchant account. During the merchant account setup you can enter the test deposit amount which will verify your Bank account.

Sounce: Tried to create a GCP billing account with a German bank as payment method, got [OR-CBAT-09] for two weeks and was given the runabout with the cloud billing support including multiple second-level support escalations. And no, support never made any useful suggestion (we are registered & paying customer).

Comment: Same problem here, had been trying for days. Thanks for the suggestion! it helped. I didn't create a Play store merchant account though, it said it costs 25 bucks. But followed the idea and created a google ads account and selected the already entered bank information, and presto! the option to enter the code was displayed in the billing section of Ads. I guess the Google Cloud developers haven't care to add the verification option during registration.Then cancelled the ads account using this https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2424604?hl=en